# why gcp cloud shell is not provisioning?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

[image]

GCP cloud shell not provisioning for more than 2 weeks. Tried to restart the shell, tried it in safe mode multiple times but still no change.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is to try accessing with a different browser, such as Google Chrome both in normal mode and in incognito mode to prevent unintended behavior from browser extensions. And see if the Cloud Shell works. [Browser](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations#browser_support) supported by Cloud Shell for your information.

Also you can try to launch the Cloud Shell from the [Console](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/launching-cloud-shell#launching_from_the_console) in GCP, to see if the issue persists or there is some change in the error/behavior.

Please check if you're not facing any of those [Limitations](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations) for Cloud Shell, the most common ones are the [Usage limits](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations#usage_limits).

> Weekly usage: Cloud Shell also has weekly usage limits. If you reach your usage limit, you'll need to wait until the specified time (listed under Usage Quota, found under the three dots menu icon) before you can use Cloud Shell again.